# Class 'SppagebuilderHelper' not found in Joomla CMS

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions

I've just started getting to grips with `Joomla` as I've been asked to customize a page. Those things that need to be customized are done with `sp` page builder. I go to "modify" in the module interface, and I'm thrown to a blank page with "Class 'SppagebuilderHelper' not found". There is nothing else, I can't localize the problem. If the site was made with sp page builder, why did it suddenly stop working now? I can't find any information on the internet, I don't know what else I can do.

```
<?php

use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper;
/**
 * @package SP Page Builder
 * @author JoomShaper http://www.joomshaper.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 - 2021 JoomShaper
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
*/
//no direct accees
defined ('_JEXEC') or die ('restricted access');

JLoader::register('ModSPagebuilderHelper', __DIR__ . '/helper.php');

$data = ModSPagebuilderHelper::getData($module->id, $params);
$moduleclass_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

require ModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_sppagebuilder', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

There is this code in `mod_sppagebuilder.php`, here it scolds on the line `$data = ModSPagebuilderHelper::getData($module->id, $params)`; specifically on `($module->(id recognizes correctly), $params)`

I tried to fix it in the admin panel but no luck, I tried to change the code from the module and compared it with the newly downloaded one to find the differences, and if anything add the missing files, but no luck.